# How to set base href in storybook?

Tags: storybook

In storybook I need to set a base address (URL) for all relative addresses (URLs) in a document. In webpack.config.js. I write:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = ({ config }) => {

  process.env.BASE_HREF_ENV =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/storibook/' : '';
```

In manager-head.html I write

```
<base href="%BASE_HREF_ENV%"/>
```

In dev mode, %BASE_HREF_ENV% is replaced by '' and it turns out `<base href=""/>.`

In production it does not change, and in the code it remains `<base href="%BASE_HREF_ENV%"/>`

How to make the corresponding value substituted instead of %BASE_HREF_ENV% in production mode?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by not using the webpack config and relying on a dedicated npm script instead:

```
"sb:build": "STORYBOOK_BASE_HREF=storybook build-storybook"
```

```
<base href="%STORYBOOK_BASE_HREF%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by busyPixels - with a slight addition:

prefixing with cross-env can be a handy one for windows users!

First run `npm install cross-env --save`

then update the script to:

```
"sb:build": "cross-env STORYBOOK_BASE_HREF=storybook build-storybook"
```